# Making UILabel touchable

Tags: iphone, user-interface, ios4, interface-builder

I have a `UILabel` and I would like to make it react to a touch. I tried putting a button on top of the label, thanks to this I could interact with the button. However, the button cannot be fully transparent, right? I could set an alpha of the button to 0,02, but it is still visible on by background. How to solve this? Maybe I could set the properties in some other way to make them fully invisible? Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First, why not just use a button and set the button title to the label's contents?

If you can't/don't want to do that, you can also set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on the label and then add a gesture recognizer to the label.

Comment: see the comment by Josh Brown down below

Answer (score 8):

In Swift:

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = true
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("labelPressed"))
label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
```

Get your click in Action :

```
func labelPressed(){
    print("Label pressed")
    //Your awesome code.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I usually do this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pushAction)];
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

I don't know if it works with labels, but then i just make a transparent UIView with the same rect and put it on top.

---

Okay, i checked, it only works in UIView, but then, do this:

```
UIView *tapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myButton.frame];
```

And put "tapView" in the addGestureRecognizer-method.

Comment: The UITapGestureRecognizer does work on UILabels - you just need to set userInteractionEnabled = YES on the UILabel.