# Adding UITapGestureRecognizer to UILabel gives error that

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

in `iOS 5.0`, i try adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to a `UILabel` in interface builder by dragging the `GestureRecognizer` from objects to the label. However, in the connections inspector for the `UILabel`, **IB** shows error message that **`UILabel` does not have collection `gesturerecognizers`**. Does this mean I need to attach the `gesture recogniser` only through code?

PS. **I've also enabled user interaction on the `UILabel` in IB**

thanks for your help on this.

Comment: chk this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206193/making-uilabel-touchable

Comment: Why not add the gesture directly in code? [labelName.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizerInstance]

Comment: I was trying to do it through IB. when adding a tap gesture through ib for uilabel, IB gives an error message but allows for the tap gesture recogniser to be added and used after setting user interaction to TRUE. this was funny, but it worked.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of you IB file. It’s very hard to understand what you have added where.