# Button/Link inside UILabel to switch to another ViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I want to show some Facebook posts inside my iOS app. I get the whole post as a JSON-object from the Graph API. Works pretty fine.

So, if a user makes a new post and tags any page inside this post, the user-id (or page-id) is also included in that JSON object, giving me the offset and length inside the text, which should link to that page. (Sounds weird, so let me give you an example):

```
{
  "id": "135416986571191_709831435796407", 
  "from": {
    "category": "Musician/band", 
    "name": "DANNIC", 
    "id": "135416986571191"
  }, 
  "to": {
    "data": [
      {
        "category": "Musician/band", 
        "name": "Tom & Jame", 
        "id": "423531801036780"
      }, 
      {
        "category": "Record label", 
        "name": "Revealed Recordings", 
        "id": "104563552952573"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "message": "Wait For You (Tom & Jame Remix) is coming out in 2 days on Revealed Recordings!", 
  "message_tags": {
    "14": [
      {
        "id": "423531801036780", 
        "name": "Tom & Jame", 
        "type": "page", 
        "offset": 14, 
        "length": 10
      }
    ], 
    "59": [
      {
        "id": "104563552952573", 
        "name": "Revealed Recordings", 
        "type": "page", 
        "offset": 59, 
        "length": 19
      }
    ]
  }, 
  "picture": "https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xfa1/v/t15.0-10/10876067_709831642463053_709831435796407_64260_924_b.jpg?oh=49c825ff152d98de125820093b5cff05&oe=5551397E&__gda__=1431085295_7c41923cf64cc0946a39e85b705ee691", 
    ....
    ....
```

As you can see, there is the "*message_tags*", which contains two page-ids, the name and *offset* and *length*. I want to replace the text in the "message" with a UIButton or just a link to that page. How can I do that?

Here is a screenshot of that post how it looks inside the Facebook App:

[image]

As you can see, the "Tom & Jame" is clickable and the rest (except "Revealed Recordings") is normal text. If you tap on 'Tom & Jame' it will switch to another View Controller showing the page of them. That's exactly what I want inside my app.

I know I could use an NSAttributedText for my label, and use the NSLinkAttributedName to make the text clickable. But I don't want my app to switch to safari and open the facebook page, I want to stay inside my app and just switch to another UIViewController, showing the infos of that page etc.

Can I use my app's url scheme for that link, even though I stay inside my app? Or can I put a UIButton inside that label and handle the tap inside my view controller?

Whats the best solution for that? Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: If you want to use the list then table view can come of some use as it has its delegate method for selecting particular item in the table cell OR if the UI is not list oriented then in that case you can display the text in UIButton and add a action to that.

Comment: I have a table view with a custom cell. The cell contains a UILabel which contains a few lines of the 'message'. And if a page is linked in that post, I want the page to be clickable. What exactly do you mean? Should I put a UIButton inside the UILabel?

Comment: Have you tried using the delegate method of table "did select row at index path" rather than making individual component clicable in the custom cell why not you write the code for navigation inside the delegate method? OR have you tried that already?

Comment: I think you don't get what I mean. Let me edit my question.

Comment: Edited it, I hope you know what I want now.

Comment: You might want to look at [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) or apple provided native [NSAttributedStrings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html)

Comment: As I said, I could use an NSAttributedText (or Label/String) for that. But how can I switch to another view controller instead of opening safari when I tap on the link?

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5206224/2053537

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is put the text in a `UITextView` and use `NSAttributedText`. I would construct the URLs in a manner that I could parse later (just enough to get `UITextView` to render a link, but it doesn't have to be a real URL on facebook).

Then I would override `shouldInteractWithURL` which is sent to the delegate of `UITextView`. Here, I could re-parse the URL, retrieve the data, and load my subsequent view controller.

Take a look at the reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:

Comment: I already implemented the UITextView and that delegate method, seems to work. The only thing is: if I set the Link-detection in the text view to true, it sometimes makes the whole text a link and not just the URL itself. And if I set the 'textView.attributedText =  ...' my app crashes?

Comment: OK fortget what I said, seems to be a bug in Xcode when using Swift. Seems to work now!